# PubNub How to handle failed requests

Tags: pubnub

I'm using Pubnub JS and need to handle subscribe request fails like 400 403 etc

addListener method don't have such option to handle error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to listen for status events and filter by category, i.e.:

```js
pubnub.addListener({
  status: function (s) {
    const affectedChannelGroups = s.affectedChannelGroups; // Array of channel groups affected in the operation
    const affectedChannels = s.affectedChannels; // Array of channels affected in the operation
    const category = s.category; // Returns category (status event)
    const operation = s.operation; // Returns PNSubscribeOperation
    const lastTimetoken = s.lastTimetoken; 
    const currentTimetoken = s.currentTimetoken; 
    const subscribedChannels = s.subscribedChannels; 
  },
});
```

For a list of categories, see https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/javascript/api-reference/configuration#listener-status-events.  I'm not sure how they map to the specific 4xx error codes but there is a dedicated PNUnknownCategory for non-200 responses.